# Migrating from bash to zsh on MacOS

Tags: macos, zsh

I am trying to migrate my .bash_profile Bash configuration to Zsh.
Thus I copied configuration to .zshrc file.

But I have two lines that fail to execute:

```
# NVM
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"
```

I am getting the following error message when sourcing the file:

```
$ source .zshrc

N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it.
```

I am new to zsh and cannot find how to solve that.

Comment: The error messages obviously does not come from Zsh, and the must occur from one of the files you are sourcing - most likely `nvm.sh`. BTW, it is pretty brave to source from Zsh a file which was obviously written for bash (`bash_completion`). I hope that you manually checked that all the files you are sourcing here indeed work for Zsh too and not only for bash.

Comment: you need to isolate the nvm files as the non working files. those files may just not work for zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just source `bash` scripts with `zsh`, especially the completion script. I suggest looking at nvm's docs to see what to do for `zsh`. You can also take a look at `"$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"` to see what it does, the only thing that matters usually is setting the `PATH` correctly. Skip the completion script entirely, those things just slow the shell.